# Error 4033 , Reason not-authorized

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I restart a GCP instance, I get the below error:

[[image: Connection error]]

Comment: Please provide some more information on this. IAP is a feature usually connected to Load-Balancers. LB have to become healthy, this can take some time.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/faq, Error Code 4033 means   "Either you don't have permission to access the instance, the instance doesn't exist, or the instance is stopped."

Given the instance exists, following https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#cloud_iap, likely you need to grant yourself the `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` permission.

Personally, I found it easier to troubleshoot such issues when connecting via `gcloud compute ssh ...` instead of the webinterface, since `gcloud` seems to give better error messages currently.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Cloud FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/faq):

> **Error Code 4033**
> Either you don't have permission to access the instance, the instance doesn't exist, or the instance is stopped.

Check if your [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) allow SSH connection, you should look for `default-allow-ssh`
If the firewall settings are correct, you can follow this guide: [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh)
I had the same problem couple of times, but they resolved themselves after couple of minutes.

Comment: @dskolli Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?